# Select menulist on Safari with Bootstrap and React

Tags: reactjs, safari, bootstrap-4

When using a `<select>` tag on Safari with React and Bootstrap Safari automatically sets the CSS value of `-webkit-appearance` to `menulist-button` even when trying to force it to remain a `menulist`.

It's simpler to play with it. You'll see the issue on Safari, and not on other Chrome or Firefox.

**Is it a bug, or is there a way to remove whatever is "triggering" this behavior?**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous"></link>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container my-3 py-3">

        <select name="outside" id="outside" className="form-control">
          <option>blue</option>
          <option>green</option>
          <option>red</option>
          <option>yellow</option>
          <option>magenta</option>
        </select>

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/loving-robinson-8722i

Answer (score 0):

The solution was twofold:

1. First use the `custom-select` class on the `<select/>` tag instead of `form-control`. That fixes the example above.
2. But since my project was using custom SCSS, I needed to make sure to rebuild it with [Autoprefixer](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/build-tools/#autoprefixer)

For the latter, it's running something like this:

```
npm install autoprefixer postcss postcss-cli
postcss styles.css -u autoprefixer
```

Thanks [@Tomas_moose](https://twitter.com/Tomas_moose)!